Gunicorn cant find working directory on a remote Ubuntu machine (Django+nginx+gunicorn)
I have django application deployed on ubuntu machine, but it doesn't work because of error in gunicorn.service (it can't find work dir I wrote).
My working directory is in /home/ubunut/project.
gunicorn.service:
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/project                                     
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/project/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock project.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I went into nginx logs:
2024/07/01 11:04:08 [error] 1906#1906: *23 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: myipaddress, server: ipaddress, request: "GET /en/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/en/", host: "ipaddress"

So i typed the  sudo journalctl -u gunicorn.service -f to see logs in real time:
Jul 01 11:29:17 landingpage (gunicorn)[2472]: gunicorn.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
Jul 01 11:29:17 landingpage systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Jul 01 11:29:17 landingpage systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 01 11:29:17 landingpage systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 01 11:29:17 landingpage systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 01 11:29:17 landingpage systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon.


I've tried to go to my project root and copy path with pwd command, checked all the permissions. Still doesn't work. How do i fix gunicorn?

Based on an updated article on DigitalOcean related to setting up systemd with gunicorn, you may want to try changing the User=root to User=ubuntu.
If you need to use the root user, then you should check the owner of the directory and the sub-directories and files within it using ls -lhR.
